# Rails: trouble understanding database relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

So I am trying to create three models, `Project`, `Entry` and `User`. A `Project` has many `Entries`, and a a `User` has many `Entries`. I scaffolded the above three models with the following commands:

```
rails g scaffold Project title:string

rails g scaffold Entry project:project_id entry_for:user_id created_by:userid \
date:string start_time:string end_time:string total:string type_of_work:string \
on_off_site:string phase:string description:text 

rails g scaffold User name:string
```

I realize that I probably totally goofed up the part where I manually put in the foreign keys for the other tables in the `Entry` model. I don't know how much `has_many` `belongs_to` automates the relationship between different models in terms of keys so I tried to add the foreign key fields manually. Is this wrong?

When I try to run `db:migrate` I get the following error:

```
undefined method `user_id' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x007fc1bdf37970>
```

Here are my migrations, as I tried to remove all of the foreign key fields but got the above error.

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateEntries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :entries do |t|
      t.string :project
      t.string :project_id
      t.user_id :entry_for
      t.user_id :created_by
      t.string :date
      t.string :start_time
      t.string :end_time
      t.string :total
      t.string :type_of_work
      t.string :on_off_site
      t.string :phase
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class RemoveColumns < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    remove_column :entries, :created_by
    remove_column :entries, :entry_for
    remove_column :entries, :project_id
  end
  def self.down
    add_column :entries, :created_by, :user_id
    add_column :entries, :entry_for , :user_id
    add_column :entries, :project_id, :string
  end
end
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In your migrations, instead of `t.user_id` you can try `t.integer` or `t.index`. That should at least get your migrations running.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to use `t.references entry_for` and then write `belongs_to :entry_for, class_name: "User"` in the `Entry` model as a means of writing my own foreign key name. For the `project` column in `entries` I realized I can similarly write `t.references project`.